# How to exclude data from a queryset in a single query in django according 2 independant fields in another related table in one to many condition

Tags: django, conditional-statements

There are 2 models, transaction and payout. There will be one transaction record and 2 payout record.
There are 2 flags in the payout record, Status & Referral. I need to get the transaction record which has The payout record Status = True and Referral = False

I have tried the following

```
queryset = queryset.exclude(payout_related_name__referral=False, payout_related_name__status=True)
```

This code is excluding the record as per first condition not according to both case combined

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    booking = models.ForeignKey(Request, related_name='request_transaction', blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField('amount', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False)
    transaction_status = models.IntegerField('Transaction Status', choices=TRANSACTION_STATUS.choices(),
                                             default=TRANSACTION_STATUS.pending, db_index=True)
    source_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('Created Date', auto_now_add=True)

class Payout(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey('Transaction', related_name='transaction_payout', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField('Transaction Status', choices=PAYOUT_STATUS.choices(),
                                 default=PAYOUT_STATUS.pending, db_index=True)
    fund_payed_out = models.DecimalField('Fund Payed Out', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    referral_payout = models.BooleanField('Referral Payout', default=False)
```

Comment: Please add your model code.

Comment: Please update the question with your models.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the related name set on the transaction field. Try updating your query to using the `transaction_payout` related name.

You are filtering on a field named `referral` but there is no field on you model with that name. There is a field with the name `referral_payout`

Next your are filtering the status field with a value of `True` but it is an `IntegerField` field. That field will never return `True`. You will have to filter on `PAYOUT_STATUS.true`.

If you want to look at one payout record you can do the below:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(transaction_payout__referral_payout=False, transaction_payout__status=PAYOUT_STATUS.true)
```

If you want to look at multiple payout records you can do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

# We use the Q method to filter with `OR`
queryset = queryset.filter(Q(transaction_payout__referral_payout=False) | Q(transaction_payout__status=PAYOUT_STATUS.true))
```

In your query you are using `exclude`. It sounds like you need filter.

Comment: This is not working because there are 2 records in payout table. transaction_payout__referral=False This query will remove the data from the list

Comment: It is still not working after updating the query to queryset = queryset.exclude(transaction_payout__referral_payout=False, transaction_payout__status=1)

Comment: What does the `base` `queryset` look like?

Comment: queryset = Transaction.objects.filter(
        booking_id=1025,
        booking__request_status=1,
        transaction_status=1
    ).prefetch_related('transaction_payout')